# Domain not resolving to GitHub pages with Godaddy

Tags: github, dns, hosting, github-pages

I have a github project and have generated a gh pages from it and is forwarding the domain from godaddy. But I am facing issues.
1. First it is a project's website and I can't add '/' and this forces me to opt for domain forwarding.
2. Second, GitHub complains about my setup and I have trouble figuring out what to do.
Thanks in advance.

[image: domain not resolving to GitHub pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/), in case you want to point the naked domain to your gh-pages add this A records:

```
your-domain.tld A 192.30.252.153
your-domain.tld A 192.30.252.154
```

For example check this project: http://go-www.com/

The [repository](https://github.com/nbari/go-www.github.io,) name needs to be `go-www.github.com` and also you need to have a [CNAME](https://github.com/nbari/go-www.github.io/blob/master/CNAME) file within the repository;

In this case, the content of the CNAME is:

```
go-www.com
```

Within your DNS provider, you will need to create a CNAME for your domain pointing to your GitHub account at github.io, for the example.

```
www.go-www.com CNAME <your-github-account>.github.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly, you can do such a thing with your Gmail to be more shorter and make you so quickly, like mailer@yahoo.com is one example, you can change your account with some none relivant letters but in a proper field like HTML5 !!!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.